# How to write mongo query in springboot criteria

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

A little assistance on how to write this query in spring boot criteria.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$field1", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$project": {"name" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```java
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("field1").count().as("count");
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").ne(null).andOperator(Criteria.where("count").gt(1)));
ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project().andExpression("_id").as("name").andExclude("_id");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(group, match, project);

mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collection", YourClass.class);
```

Docs:

- [GroupOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/GroupOperation.html)
- [MatchOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/MatchOperation.html)
- [ProjectionOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperation.html)

And a [Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations).